# What's it called when someone gets a job because they "bought" it?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is it called when someone gets a job because they "bought" it?

Comment: Bribery. But it's far from specific to jobs.

Comment: *Racketeering* touches on the issue, as does *payola*.  And of course *nepotism* comes close.  *Graft* also comes close.  (But several minutes searching a thesaurus site didn't yield anything that was "dead on".)

Answer (score 0):

A [***kickback***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kickback) —

> a payment (as of money or property) made to one in a position to open up or control a source of income for the payer

— is a type of bribe.  It is typically paid after the fact
(e.g., “You authorize the treasury to pay me $1000 to paint City Hall,
and then I’ll pay you $100”) and is typically associated with *contracts*,
but it could certainly be used for somebody who hired you.